# Ruby on Rails has_many_through with validation and logic to ensure only one record in the join table which is updated as required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the Course model which has a number of has many through associations with the User model with join table CourseUser. The join table has an attribute type_str which specifies which role the user takes on. I have added validation to ensure that only one record is present in the join table for each course, user pair. The problem is ensuring that this record is updated if it is already present, rather than adding a new one which of course makes validation fail.

User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

...
  has_many :courses_enrolled_on, :through => :course_enrollees, :source => :course, :conditions => { :course_users => { :type_str => "enrollee" } }

  has_many :course_users
  has_many :courses, :through => :course_users, :source => :course, :readonly => true 
end
```

Course class

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :course_enrollees, :conditions => { :type_str => "enrollee" }, :class_name => CourseUser
  has_many :enrollees, :through => :course_enrollees, :source => :user

  has_many :course_users
  has_many :users, :through => :course_users, :source => :user, :readonly => true
end
```

Course class:

```
class CourseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user

   validates_uniqueness_of :course_id, :scope => :user_id
end
```

Comment: The answer will depend on the code you are using to create your `course_user` records.

Comment: I am just using the << operator to add to the collections. E.g. 
enrollees << user